# ¿Cómo puedo poner un icono en código Java Script? En ves de los símbolos un icono fas fa-chevron-down

Tags: javascript, function, font-awesome

¿Cómo puedo poner un icono en código JavaScript? En ves de los símbolos un icono fas fa-chevron-down

```js
  

$(function(){
    $("#botonEsconder").click(function(){
        $( ".divEsconder" ).toggle();
        $(this).text(function(i, text){
            return text === "Mostrar ►" ? "Ocultar ▼" : "Mostrar ►";
        })
    });
});
```

```html
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="botonEsconder">Ocultar ▼</button>
<div class="divEsconder">
    <p>Hola</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que pases a la lecturas de los siguientes artículos: 
https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask y 
https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example y 
https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic y 
https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: sinceramente no termino de entender el problema o tu pregunta...

Comment: Lisseth, Bienvenida a SO en Español... te recomiendo que vayas y te des un [tour] para saber como funciona el sitio, y luego vayas a [ask] para mejorar la calidad de tus preguntas, tal como está solo obtendrás puntuaciones negativa y/o reportes...  Muchisima suerte

Comment: quieres remplazar este simbolo ▼ por por uno de font-awesone???

Comment: Por favor, sé mas puntual con tu pregunta, puedes decirnos que estas haciendo? con que herramientas lo estas haciendo?, que has intentado hasta ahora?, tienes imágenes del resultado que deseas?, etc... Todo lo que sea relevante para poder responder. Recuerda, si tu pregunta es mala, los resultados q obtendrás también lo serán.

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez-TodoPoderoso Si deseo reemplazar ese símbolo por un de  font-awesone

Comment: @Lisseth tienes entonces que incluir la libreria de font aweson en tu proyecto y modificar el atributo class...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta función es la versión 2 de mi respuesta, y la que tendría que ser la más aceptada.

Solo hice unos cambios para que cambie el texto del botón, y gire el ícono.

```js
  

  $(function(){
  $("#botonEsconder").click(function(){
   $( ".divEsconder" ).toggle();
  
 $(".fa").toggleClass("rotar");
 
 // Debe haber una clase en CSS
 $(this).toggleClass('cambio');
 
 if ($(this).hasClass('cambio')) {
   
   $("#botonEsconder .texto").text("Mostrar");
   
  } else {
   $("#botonEsconder .texto").text("Ocultar");
  }
 
 });
});
```

```css
.cambio {
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.fa {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 5px;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.fa.rotar {
 transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

```html
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <button type="button" id="botonEsconder">
   
   <!-- con este span trabaja jQuery para el cambio de texto -->
   <span class="texto">Ocultar</span> 
   
   <span class="fa fa-chevron-down">A</span>
   
   </button>
  <div class="divEsconder">
    <p >Hola</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Sii gracias por la ayudaa

Comment: Olvide agregar un efecto más a tu **div** que ocultas: ```$(".divEsconder").slideToggle();``` por si te gusta. Pero creo que eso ya sabes todo

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias maneras de hacer que un ícono gire al presionar un botón. Lo más fácil y rápido que puedo mostrarte es lo siguiente:

Dentro del botón (al final del texto) agrega un `span`, y al `span` una clase de `fa fa-chevron-down` (si estás usando la librería de **font awesome**):

```
<span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span>
```

Luego en tu estilo **CSS** define al `span` o a la clase dentro del `span` así:

```js
  

  $(function(){
  $("#botonEsconder").click(function(){
   $( ".divEsconder" ).toggle();
  
 $(".fa").toggleClass("rotar");
 
 });
});
```

```css
.fa {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 5px;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.fa.rotar {
 transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

```html
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <button type="button" id="botonEsconder">Ocultar <span class="fa fa-chevron-down">A</span></button>
  <div class="divEsconder">
    <p >Hola</p>
  </div>
```

Como muestra para ver en esta página, le puse la letra "A" en `span` para que se visualiza el efecto. Luego podés sacar porque si el `span` contiene un font awesome, la letra A le va estorbar.
Podés cambiarle el icono ...

Comment: Entiendo, pero ya no cambia el texto a mostrar , lo que deseo es que cambie el texto del botón de ocultar a mostrar el div con un icono  font-awesone

Comment: Ok ya entendí. No tenía lógica cambiar solo el icono. Voy a ver cómo sería eso